# HTML & Javascript not working well together in my sample of code

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why the code got no error but isn't displaying the message in JavaScript in the mood function ! It's only displaying the div.

```js
function mood() {
  var box = document.getElementById('t');
  document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = "Hey <strong>Thanks!</strong>";

}
```

```html
<div onload="mood()" style="display: block" id="t">HEYYYYY</div>
```

Comment: I think you should put the onload on body, not on div

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly !

Comment: [Read about the event `DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the onload in body instead of div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>MA page web</title>
            <script> 
            function mood(){
                var box = document.getElementById('t');
                document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = "Hey <strong>Thanks!</strong>";
            }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="mood()">
            <div  style="display: block" id="t">HEYYYYY</div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var box = document.getElementById('t');
function mood() {
  box.innerHTML = "Hey <strong>Thanks!</strong>";
}
window.addEventListener('load', mood)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>MA page web</title>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <divstyle="display: block" id="t">HEYYYYY</div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can use an event listener. This waits until the window is loaded and then runs the function. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The `onload` attribute is only supported on the following HTML tags: `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input type="image">`, `<link>`, `<script>` and `<style>`.

I've adjusted your example below, moving the `onload` attribute to the body tag in this instance.

```js
function mood() {
  var box = document.getElementById('t');
  document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = "Hey <strong>Thanks!</strong>";

}
```

```html
<body onload="mood()"> 
   <div id="t" style="display: block">HEYYYYY</div> 
</body>
```